# how to erase subviews from a view?

Tags: iphone, ios4

This is my code. I am using this code to erase only the `imageView.image`, but I want to erase the imageview subviews also. How can I erase the subviews from imageView?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);
[imageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height)];
CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGImageAlphaNone);    //kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 10);
CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1, 0, 0, 10);
CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), point.x, point.y);
//this line code for erasing select the part of the image
CGContextClearRect (UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, 30, 30)); 
//End the code
CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using `[imageView removeFromSuperview]`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove all subviews for some reason, you can try:

```
for (UIView *view in imageView.subviews) {
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```